# Leaflet circle doesn't show on map

Tags: leaflet, html, svg

I have a Leaflet application that uses circles. It works fine when I don't put the script in my HTML template (I use SingApp template), but when I integrate the script with the template, the circle does not appear on top of my map.

This is how it looks when I use it without the HTML template (SingApp template):

[image]

And here I put the script into the template:

[image]

I've checked the HTML element, there is a circle SVG element in the HTML document.

```
<svg class="leaflet-zoom-animated" width="1902" height="406" viewBox="-301 -64 1902 406" style="transform: translate3d(-301px, -64px, 0px);"><g><path stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="0.5" stroke-width="5" fill="#f03" fill-opacity="0.3" class="leaflet-clickable" d="M434,140A52,52,0,1,1,433.9,140 z"></path></g></svg>
```

but still, circle does not appear on top of my map. I think there is conflict with template, but i dont know how to deal with it.

Comment: Can you add more of the code you are using, and perhaps how your directory is structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the exactly the same problem today. It was an absolute devil to debug, but in my instance I had some styles on the svg element - specifically a height:100% and width:100% that was causing them to override the default height/width of the element itself and prevented them from showing.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the map, try to specify the following option:
preferCanvas: true
In my case it solved the problem.